# How to have multiple branches in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to figure out how to manage my dag in `Apache Airflow`.

There are a few master steps that I need to.
for example, let's say `step 1` and `step 2` should always be executed before branching out. And then steps `A, B, C, D, E` should all be concurrently branched out after `step 2`, and each of these have their own steps.. so like `A1, A2..` same with `B~E`.

What's the best way of managing it? It looks like there is `BranchOperator` but it says it's really good for alerts, and I'm not trying to do alerts here but actually use operators for `A1, A2..` steps. Should `A-E` be all subdags? If so, how do I trigger subdags?

Answer (score 3):

If you want structure like this:

```
               -> A1 -> A2 -> ...
              /
step1 -> step2 -> B1 -> B2 -> ...
              \ 
               -> C1 -> C2 -> ...
```

Then you can just set dependency in your DAG as

```
step1 >> step2
step2 >> A1 >> A2 >> ...
step2 >> B1 >> B2 >> ...
step2 >> C1 >> C2 >> ...
```

BranchOperator is used when you have conditional branches (if X then execute A else B).

Comment: If there are tons of An, and Bn operators.. would it be smart to manage it this way maybe? `step2 >> subdagA`, `step2 >> subdagB`, and within the `subdagA`, I could have `A1, A2`.. and so on?

Comment: I have a situation where a "concurrent" branch is not running or even being queued; Complains "*** Task instance did not exist in the DB" even though can see the branch in the webserver GUI. Do you know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to concurrently execute all the Tasks A,B,C..etc? If so, then `branchOperator` may not be suitable. `branchOperator` selects a particular branch based some logic.